# How do I fix the second value of insertion sorting in tuple to work as well with the first value

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

Basically, I am trying to do Insertion Sorting on a tuple which is stored inside a vector, and I have a function to do it, when I only use the **first** value (`get<0>(tupleVector[i])`) it works, but when I try to add the **second** value (`get<1>(tupleVector[i])`) it doesn't, here's the whole function code.

```
void sort(vector<tuple<size_t, size_t>>& tupleVector, vector<int> idVector){
    // insertionSort
    for (int i = 1; i < tupleVector.size(); i++) {
        int key = get<0>(tupleVector[i]);
        int key2 = get<1>(tupleVector[i]);
        int j = i;

        while (j > 0 && get<0>(tupleVector[j - 1]) > key && get<1>(tupleVector[j - 1]) > key2) {
            get<0>(tupleVector[j]) = get<0>(tupleVector[j - 1]);
            get<1>(tupleVector[j]) = get<1>(tupleVector[j - 1]);
            j--;
        }

        get<0>(tupleVector[j]) = key;
        get<1>(tupleVector[j]) = key2;
    }
    cout << "Sorted" << endl;
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to give examples of how it doesn't work, if I use values like **([500, 100], [700, 100], [100, 100], [500, 200])** it just doesn't sort anymore, but if I remove the (`get<1>(tupleVector[i])`) then it sorts based on the first value, but I need to sort for both, there's no compiler error or anything, it just doesn't sort

Comment: how does it not work? Is there a compiler error? Unexpected output? And please post a [mcve]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std::sort`?

Comment: Basically, it doesn't sort correctly, let's say I use ([500, 100], [700, 100], [100, 100], [500, 200]), it doesn't sort, it literally just doesn't sort.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, we're not allowed to, it's for an assignment, I managed to make it work if you remove the get<1>(tupleVector) which is the second value but I need to sort it based on first and second

Comment: your comparison is a little odd. `{1,3}` vs `{3,1}` are considered equivalent by your condition. Note that `std::tuple` does have a `<`. Further note that even if you want a comparison different from tuples `<` you can use `std::sort`

Comment: If you have a school (or similar) assignment or exercise, then please include the full text of the assignment/exercise, including all requirements and limitations. It will make it easier for us to help you. Also please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: also the assignment can be simply `tuplevector[j] = tuplevector[j-1];`

Comment: i honestly dont know what is the issue, but things are much simpler if you do not use unnecessary `get` calls. Maybe that already solves the issue

Comment: please read about [mcve] and provide one, also include input, output and expected output in the question. As I mentioned your comparison looks odd, and as you didnt tell us what exactly is the task we cannot know if you simply  need `std::tuple::operator<` or maybe something else

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number actually that fixed it, I didn't have to separate, it just made sure that the type of key was the actual tuple and it sorted, appreciate it man!

Comment: well, it did sort, the issue was just that your definition of what it means for one element to come before another element was off. Note that comments were merely meant to ask for clarification of the question. It would still be nice if you would edit the question with requested information, because as it currently stands one can only guess

Comment: Is `operator<` for `std::tuple` allowed (in contrast to `std::sort`)? If so, then use it, it does a lexicographic comparison on its individual values. Otherwise you need to adjust your comparison operator; lexicographically a pair or tuple of two values is smaller than another if either first value is smaller (that alone suffices!) or if first value is equal and second value is smaller, i.e. `get<0>(x) < get<0>(y) || get<0>(x) == get<0>(y) && get<1>(x) < get<1>(y)`; compare strings: `ax` is smaller than `ba`, no matter if second character is smaller or not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you intend a lexicographical comparison then your comparison operator fails to do so.

Assume you want to compare ordinary strings lexicographically:

Your operator would then accept `xx` as smaller to `zz`, as both characters in first string are smaller than the ones in second string – however this requirement fails to compare one of `xz` and `zx` as smaller than the other, as in neither string both characters are smaller as in the other one; thus neither of `xz < zx` nor `zx < xz` applies meaning both strings are considered equivalent with the consequence that when being sorted they are allowed to appear in *arbitrary* order.

Lexicographically one of these strings is already smaller if just the first of these characters is smaller, i.e. `xy` is smaller than both `zx` *and* `zz`, no matter if second character is smaller, equal or larger. On the other hand one string cannot be smaller if already first character is greater (obviously…) – i.e. to be smaller even if first character is not then first character needs to be *equal*. In this case the second character being smaller defines the entire string being smaller: `xy` is smaller than `xz`, but neither than `xy` nor than `xx`.

So as summary, you compare lexicographically two values by `x[0] < y[0] || x[0] == y[0] && x[1] < y[1]` – and you can apply this analogously to your tuples.

Generalised to arbitrary length then you can iterate over all characters of the strings `x` and `y` (testing `x < y`) or all members of the tuple respectively, returning `true` immediately if you encounter a value smaller in `x` than in `y`, `false` if you encounter a value greater and just continue iterating otherwise – until you encounter the end of one of the strings/tuples. If then `y` has further characters/members `x` still is smaller, otherwise not. Solely that iterating over tuples more complicated than with strings…

Comment: Perfect explanation man, thank you, I understand this much better now, I'll mark this as the answer so people know!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `(get<0>(tupleVector))` wasn't needed at all, I just changed it so that it sorted the tuple without needing to use two comparison checks, here's the updated code

```
void sort(vector<tuple<size_t, size_t>>& tupleVector){
    // insertionSort
    for (int i = 1; i < tupleVector.size(); i++) {
        tuple<size_t, size_t> key = (tupleVector[i]);
        int j = i;

        while (j > 0 && (tupleVector[j - 1]) > key) {
            (tupleVector[j]) = (tupleVector[j - 1]);
            j--;
        }

        (tupleVector[j]) = key;
    }
    cout << "Sorted" << endl;
}
```

Comment: if you want lexicographical ordering you should mention that in the question. Lexicographical is rather common, and what you get from `<`, but it is by far not the only one. Answering your own question is completely fine, but the question lacks details first. You can answer it because you know what you want, but others would have to guess